# Are 'Has' Properties Good Practice?

Tags: c#, mvvm, properties

Sometimes in my models, I implement get only 'Has' properties (e.g. `HasDescription`) so I can easily check the validity of a property from outside my model with `if (model.HasDescription) { ... }`.

The implementation might look something like:

```
public bool HasDescription => Description != null && Description != string.Empty;
```

Is this good practice? More specifically, if I do take this approach should I move this conditional logic elsewhere? Perhaps into extension methods?

Comment: Another approach might be to use an extension method with `LinqExpression`, such as `.Has(m -> m.Description)`.

Comment: Primarily opnion-based --> to be closed.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Brutal. What's your 'opinion' on the matter then, before you close it?

Comment: It depends (as usual). Which layer or component do you want to contain the validation logic?  Because this HasDecription property implements and defines the requirement here. When called from a Validation layer, this is wrong.

Comment: The reason why this topic is closed is because there *is* no single answer to be accepted which is the whole point of StackOverflow. This kind of question attracts very many different opinion-based answers which themeselfes are based on personal likes and dislikes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of personal preference sometimes; having a bunch of HasX properties can be OK.  I sometimes do it for validation reasons (I found it works well to use a property like that for an MVC app when using [FoolProof](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/)).  It can be cumbersome to have to add a bunch  of HasX properties though...  So, if you are using these for evaluations in your controller, it's a matter of personal preference.  If that is the approach you want to take, I wouldn't worry about it.

If you are using it for validation purposes, sometimes when you need model-based evaluation, you can use an IsValid method for determining validation status.  That would be more MVVM-like than MVC-like, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

`Has` is completely legitimate. However, the logic belongs in the setter or in the constructor: decide on a way to represent a missing property (`null` or `string.Empty`, preferably `null`, but definitely not both). This leaves the `Has` logic to check for `null`.

One consideration in favor of dropping `Has` altogether is the possibility of using `??` operator. If your use cases allow you to replace

```
var xyz;
if (x.HasXyz) {
    xyz = h.Xyz;
} else {
    xyz = defaultValueOfXyz;
}
```

with

```
var xyz = h.Xyz ?? defaultValueOfXyz;
```

then you can drop `HasXyz` altogether.